# What are the divisors $P,2P,3P,...$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, riemann-surfaces, divisors-algebraic-geometry

The definition of divisor I know is: Let $X$ be a Riemann surface, a divisor is a map $D\colon X \to \mathbb{Z}$ such that for every compact $K \subset X$ only finitely many points $x\in X$ have $D(x) \neq 0$. (From Forster's Lectures on Riemann Surfaces).

I do not understand what $D = nP$ is supposed to mean for $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $P$ a point. What precisely is the definition of nP? What is the geometric intuition behind this?

A comment on my background: I know classical algebraic geometry and compact Riemann surfaces as far as Forster's book goes.

Comment: The quick answer is that mirrors the differential-geometric construction of a line bundle.  The divisor $P$ gives the line bundle which is the result of gluing the trivializations over $X-P$ and a small disc around $P$ by the transition function $z$, a local coordinate at $P$, hence the poles&zeros interpretation of global sections.

Comment: @user10354138 Thanks. Could you clarify on what a trivialisation is?

Comment: More simply, $nP$ is the map $X\to \mathbb{Z}$ which sends $P$ to $n$, and all other points to $0$.

Comment: @CaptainLama Thanks!

Comment: The other main thing to know is that divisors exist to capture the notions of "set where a meromorphic function vanishes, with multiplicity" and "set where a meromorphic function blows up, with multiplicity." On a Riemann surface, these sets are finite, hence just sets of points. We then tag these points with coefficients to encode the multiplicity (so e.g. the function $f(z) = z^2$ has as its "divisor of zeroes" the origin with coefficient $2$). And of course a finite set with multiplicities is (purely formally) the same thing as a function $X \to \mathbb Z$ with finite support.